# Choosing element in array dependently on if-statement

Tags: ruby

I would like to print one of two strings dependently on the condition value in Ruby.

Of course it can be always done in the most classic way:

```
if a==1 then puts "Yes!" else puts "No!" end
```

or even

```
puts (a==1 ? "Yes!" : "No!")
```

but I'm looking for more Ruby/Python way using lists/arrays. In Python it can be done with:

```
print ['Yes', 'No'][1==2]
```

**Is there any similar way to achieve this with Ruby?** The code above (written in Ruby) doesn't work, because of boolean value as an index and it doesn't work even if I'd try `(1==2).to_i`...
Any ideas?

Comment: ['yes', 'no'][(1==2) ? 0 : 1] ?

Comment: Personally if you want it short as possible then I can only think of 1 == 2 ? 'yes' : 'no'

Comment: @NabeelAmjad, actually - yes, you're right, this is also the short one. I was just really curious about the Python way as I mentioned.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses in the second code: `puts a == 1 ? "Yes!" : "No!"`. And you still want it shorter? Besides the minimum things that express your information (`puts`, `a == 1`, `"Yes!"`, and `"No"`), there are only two characters extra: `?` and `:`. How can it be shorter?

Comment: Oh, @sawa. I didn't expect it to be shorter than the code with conditional operator, it is already short - I completely agree.

Comment: And actually, the Python way is not Rubyish. It is ugly. It stands on associating certain integers with boolean. But that is arbitrary. Ruby doesn't handle integers like that. That is cleanness of Ruby.

Comment: More craziness: `puts ["Yes!", "No!"][[1].index(a) || 1]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided that your `a` is numeric, you can do this:

```
puts ["Yes!", "No!"][a <=> 1]
```

Comment: Clever!  - It makes use of fact that array element at index `1` can be accessed using index `-1`as well.

Comment: Very clever indeed, but I'm not sure I'd like to see something like this in my code :)

Comment: Comparable is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen python way in ruby world

but you can open class.

```
class TrueClass
  def to_agreement   # any method name you want
    'Yes'
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def to_agreement
    'No'
  end
end
```

Or, I suggest use module

```
module Agreementable
  def to_agreement
    self ? 'Yes' : 'No'
  end
end

TrueClass.include Agreementable
FalseClass.include Agreementable
```

Above both two way, You can use

```
true.to_agreement #=> 'Yes'
false.to_agreement #=> 'No'
(1==2).to_agreement #=> 'No'
```

It is ruby way.

Comment: I was rather trying to make my code shorter with some Python-like built-in trick, bro. I hope there is any other way.

Answer (score 2):

```
puts({true => 'Yes', false => 'No'}[a == 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

`puts (if a == 1 then "Yes!" else "No!" end)`

Answer (score 1):

You could add `to_i` method to `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`

```
class TrueClass
    def to_i
        1
    end
end

class FalseClass
    def to_i
        0
    end
end


p ['yes', 'no'][(2==2).to_i]
```